# gcc - structures as label for debugging

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

#### Context:

Linux 64.

I would like a way to tell gcc to keep the structure as they are when generating assembly with `gcc -O0 -S -g myprog.c`

By that, I mean: instead of referencing the structure by address, I would like them to be referenced by label. That would ease the parsing without reading the source code again.

So, for example:

```
struct mystruct{
    int32_t a;
    char * b;
}
```

would become something like:

```
label_mystruct:
    -4(label_mystruct)
    -12(label_mystruct)
```

and for example, referenced by:

```
add $56, -4(label_mystruct)
```

Currently, it is referenced like

```
.globl _main
_main:
LFB13:
LM157:
    pushq %rbp  #
LCFI27:
    movq %rsp, %rbp#,
LCFI28:
    subq $80, %rsp#,
    movl %edi,-68(%rbp) # argc, argc,
    movq %rsi,-80(%rbp) # argv, argv

    Next line is the culprit:
    movq -56(%rbp), %rdx # list, D.3781
    movq -16(%rbp), %rax # arr, D.3780
    movq %rdx, %rsi # D.3781,
    movq %rax, %rdi # D.3780,
    call _myaddhu   #
```

I would like it to be

```
label_mystruct:
    -4(label_mystruct)
    -12(label_mystruct)

.globl _main
_main:
LFB13:
LM157:
    pushq %rbp  #
LCFI27:
    movq %rsp, %rbp#,
LCFI28:
    subq $80, %rsp#,
    movl %edi,-68(%rbp) # argc, argc,
    movq %rsi,-80(%rbp) # argv, argv

    Now it is fine:
    movq label_mystruct, %rdx # list, D.3781
    movq -16(%rbp), %rax # arr, D.3780
    movq %rdx, %rsi # D.3781,
    movq %rax, %rdi # D.3780,
    call _myaddhu   #
```

#### Question:

Is that possible with gcc and without using external tools?

Comment: What does "to keep the structure as they are" mean? The order is guaranteed to be the same (with some exceptions for bitfields, AFAIK). Are you referring to padding?

Comment: My problem is that I loose the information of the way the structure is defined. When parsing, I would like to be able to know where I am in the structure without having to read the source code again. I've just edited the question.

Comment: What does "where I am" mean? How do you parse? You have to be specific or this'll be an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) nobody's gonna solve.

Comment: Updated the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that if you put your struct into static storage. This of course alters the meaning of the code. For example, this code

```
struct {
    int a, b;
} test;

int settest(int a, b) {
    test.a = a;
    test.b = b;
}
```

compiles to (cleaned up):

```
settest:
    movl    %edi, test(%rip)
    movl    %esi, test+4(%rip)
    ret

    .comm   test,8,4
```

You could also try to pass the option `-fverbose-asm` to gcc which instructs gcc to add some annotations that might make the assembly easier to read.

Comment: I did that already but it obliges me to parse after the '#'. It is better than nothing but still not ideal

Comment: @Larry I don't think you can get any better, especially considering that there isn't really a fixed address for every variable with modern compilers.

Comment: You are right; I will give you the points for the solutions you propose, even  if i did that already. ;)

Comment: I tried clang, and it didn't output better assembly to help me :( I think I will keep your answer. I guess it would be awesome if you suggested the fverbose-asm first in your answer, because, it helps getting the problem solved. It may be the closest thing possible without massive re-engineering :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, and this is by the setup used in GCC.

The problem here is that the struct here is stored on the stack and you cannot really have a label referring to something on the stack. If the struct was not on the stack it would have had a label referring to it (for example if it were a global variable).

What you have on the other hand is that GCC would generate debugging info which has information about what data is placed when running specific code. In your example it would in essense say that "when executing this code -56(%ebp) points to `mystruct`".

On the other hand if you would write assembler code by hand you could certainly have symbolic references to a variable. You could for example do:

```
#define MYSTRUCT -56(%ebp)

...
movq MYSTRUCT, %rdx
```

however the `MYSTRUCT` will be expanded and that symbol being lost during assembling the code. It would be of no help if GCC did this (except maybe that the assembler code generated by `-s` could be more readable), in addition GCC does not pass the assembler through preprocessor anyway (because it don't do this).

Comment: Sounds to me OP wants to simply see a structure always accessed as [basepointer+fieldoffset], where the basepointer is the address of the first field.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: this.